# 256 colors in zsh-syntax-highlighting?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

OK, so I'm using this little fancy cutting edge technology called zsh-syntax-highlighting and although I'm overall happy with the result I don't know how to set styles to anything but 8 basic colors (black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white), e.g.

```
#works
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=red'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=1'

#doesn't work
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=31m'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=\e[31m'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=%{\e[31m%}'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='31m'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='\e[31m'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='%{\e[31m%}'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='%{\e[1;38;5;118m%}'
```

So, how do I set more fancy colors for this zshzle plugin?

Comment: you can get the xterm color list from 0-255 from the link - https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/ and set it like `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=177'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out in the comment to [chepner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365320/3620917) `terminator` is a fork of `gnome-terminal` and it still uses a lot of functions from gnome. In fact it seems that the whole `terminator` [VTE widget](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html) comes from gnome and gnome-terminal by defaults "supports" only 8 basic colors. You can check that with `echotc Co` command. It will return 8 for both of them and for `xterm` too (although in `xterm` case this is true and only 8 colors), so basically all 3 terminal emulators you tried so far.

Now, you noted that teminator (and gnome-terminal) can in fact display more colors, but this is only because it more or less processes all those special color codes without paying attention to TERM settings what does not obey standards but well, this is gnome. Anyway to make long story short you need to set `TERM` environment variable to something like `xterm-256color` and check again with `echotc Co` - you should now see `256`, and your `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=217'` should work as well.

To always start with 256 colors you can put into you .zshrc

```
[[ "$TERM" == "xterm" ]] && export TERM=xterm-256color
```

and if you have any gnome shortcuts with `terminator` then change them as follows

```
terminator -e "TERM=xterm-256color pine"
```

Answer (score 1):

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting suggests that the value for `fg` be a single integer from 0 to 255:

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=167'  # Whatever color 167 is in the 256-color palette.
```

Comment: What does it do? Are you sure you have a 256-color terminal?

Comment: It just doesn't change anything - color stays as my default (which is from 256 palette by the way). I use `terminator` as my terminal which is "clone" of gnome-terminal and I'm sure it can display 256 colors because I can set them in prompt, completion style, and `echo -e '%{\e[38;5;123m%} foo %{\e[0m%}'` works too.

Comment: BTW, I tried in standard `gnome-terminal` and `xterm` as well. It seems to me that it is problem with this zle plugin/widget and not with terminals. Does it work for you?

Comment: I only suggested it because it wasn't on the list of things you tried. What about `ZSH_...[path]=167`?

Answer (score 1):

1. I Notice you are using [path], it could be that a custom path with it's own color setting is interfering with your highlight setting. Try testing with a different item such as [command]:

   ```
   ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=222'
   ```

   I tried the above line and it works for me. I tried using the same value for path already knowing my custom prompt has its own colors and my prompts custom colors won out over the highlight.
2. I use a ZSH helper called Oh-My-ZSH so the following may be a bit different or not apply to you:

   Make sure you are changing the color definition after the highlight plugin is loaded. On my setup it will actually generate an error but since I only tested on my syetem (OSX10,9, ZSH 5.0.7, Oh-My-ZSH, iTerm v2) your experience may be different.

   Doesn't work:

   ```
   ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=222'
   ...
   plugins=(git osx jim colorize zsh-syntax-highlighting)
   ```

   Does work:

   ```
   plugins=(git osx jim colorize zsh-syntax-highlighting)
   ...
   ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=222'
   ```

Comment: "On my setup it will actually generate an error" - do you recall what the error was? I'm aware of reference-to-undefined errors in strict environments, but the converse sounds *pathologically* strict. Maybe the existence of the value was used as a canary for double-inclusion?